# PDF error when downloading/saving but not when viewing in browser (first page blank)

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdf, download, readfile

We have had a site for many years, PHP on Ubuntu where clients can download forms/letters as pdfs, then upload them when completed.

Now when re-downloading client's uploaded multi-page pdf, the first (cover) page is blank and Adobe acrobat says "error exists on page...".  When we ftp the document, the file is fine with no errors, so the problem has to be in the file download / readfile() process.

This error occurs in both Chrome & Firefox (all updated).  If you just view the pdf in the browser, the cover page appears to be fine and readable, however, if you download it you get the same adobe error and blank first page.  I am at a loss for how to diagnose this.

Below is the PHP code we use to pull the file.

Please note, for security reasons we do not allow linking directly to any files.  The link is to a php page that validates an encoded file request for permission to read a file, then pulls the correct file info from the database for that user, then reads the file and serves it back to the client.  I have not included the validation or database related code, just the relevant readfile code:

```
header("Content-Length: " . filesize('/filestore/' . $doc['filename']));
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date in the past
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $docname . '.' . strtolower(end(explode('.', $doc['filename']))) . '"');
header("Pragma: private");
readfile('/filestore/'  . $doc['filename']);
```

Additional info based on questions in comments:

To prevent direct linking and brute force scraping of documents, the file store is not in a public folder (so no direct linking).

User links look something like this My File with the id encoded with the file info and CSRF token plus session token checks as part of the validation. The download.php file validates the user and file to make sure they have permission to the document then calls the code above to obtain and "serve" the file to the browser.

$docname is the client's original filename for the file stored in the database.  We save files with our own generated file name to prevent naming conflicts when clients use the same file name, this is stored in the DB as $doc['filename'].  We restore the client's filename when downloading.

Comment: That `Content-Type` header looks peculiar `"pdf"=>"application/pdf"`

Comment: actually the full code has a function call that pulls the content type (since clients sometimes upload pics rather than pdfs).  I just pasted in the result for this example that was a pdf, and I pasted it wrong.  Fixed in question now.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: `readfile(('/filestore/'  . $doc['filename']);` has 1 too few braces! The closing `)` is missing

Comment: readfile extra ( was removed.  This was a copy paste error, not in original code.  Thanks for catch

Comment: So `$docname` is defined **before** it is called here is it?

Comment: yes, its stored in the database.  I didn't include all the validation and database calls.  $docname is usually something like "myorderform" or something.  We don't use client filenames for both security and to prevent naming conflicts.

Comment: Have you tried to confirm whether this happens with a file that you have manually placed using FTP and built suitable db entries? IE: is there some portion of the websites upload routine that introduces anomalies that would not be present if the file were uploaded by ftp.

Comment: _"Please note, for security reasons we do not allow linking directly to any files."_ - so you must have a similar code for _"just view the pdf in the browser"_ then? What are the significant differences between that, and the code you have shown for downloading the file?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius - With our locally generated files we have not had any issues.  FTP downloads of uploaded files are fine, so I assume its not related to the upload, but I will try more testing to confirm.  I am assuming the code I posted (after the edits) looks ok?

Comment: @CBroe This is the only way they can obtain a pdf from our system.  The browser settings determine if they open it to view or download.  Files they can download are listed something like <ahref="download.php?id=dkljfsdjoiweoiq">My File</a>  with the id encoded with the file info and CSRF token plus session token checks as part of the validation.  the download.php file has the code above to obtain and "serve" the file to the browser once the request is validated.  The file store is not in a public folder, to prevent direct linking and brute force scraping

Comment: The edited PHP looks OK as far as I can tell - a little different to the code I tend to use for that purpose.

Comment: What happens when you remove the `Expires` and `Pragma` headers?